# Displaying frame buffer images on external monitor

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, display

I have a laptop connected to an external monitor. It's running a fairly fresh installation of ubuntu 18.04. The laptop is closed, so external monitor is listed as primary when I run `xrandr`. What I would like to do is display an image on this external monitor such that it fills the whole screen, using the command line (in particular, I want to do this over ssh).

So far I've been using the `fbi` command like so:
`sudo fbi -T 7 -a image.jpg`.
This displays the image, but it only takes up 3/4 of the space of the monitor. The rest of the space is just black. However, when I open the lid of the laptop, the image does indeed fill in the entire laptop screen (the image on the external monitor is unaffected by my opening the laptop lid). What can I do to make the image fill up the external monitor?